# Are there any workarounds for Grails sitemesh not supporting if statements with open HTML body tags

Tags: grails, template-engine, gsp, sitemesh

I have a GSP with the below code..

```
 <g:if test="${'Ethan Hunt'.equals(agentName)}">
 <body>
       Secret Mission
 </g:if>
        Unclassified stuff
  </body>
```

Right now this gives an exception..

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException:         
Grails tag [sitemesh:captureBody] was not closed
```

According to [this](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5626), such usage is not supported in Grails using sitemesh for layouts and the only workaround is to set sitemesh.preprocess config to false.

But that post is fairly old so I was wondering if there are any better workarounds now?

Of course an obvious one would be to re-factor the code to move the if check inside the body but supposing that was not an option (this sample is a simplification of my actual code where this refactor option would not work).

Are there any other options to avoid this exception but still keep this code?

Comment: How about an un-simplified example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no better workarounds other than refactoring the code or turning off pre-processing (which impacts performance quite a lot).

Not much has changed with both Sitemesh and Grails use of Sitemesh since then.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I guess the only option is the painful task of refactoring the actual code.